# Delays sending 4.5k emails in quick succession via PHPMailer and Mail Relay

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have PHPmailer setup and working a treat.
It’s basic code whereby it breaks down a variable of emails and for each email, it triggers a mail send.

But as you can predict, when there is around 4500 emails, it takes some time and I need to try speed it up.
It took 12 minutes to send.

Whilst the 12 minutes isn’t a lot in the grand scheme of things, I still want to explore how I can reduce this.

The code is running on one server which then uses an in house company owned mail relay server with our own network. So there is no throttling on any part here.

I’ve been trying to do research but struggling to find a solution, does anyone have any ideas?
Is there a way I can trigger multiple sends all at once maybe?

Based on everyones comments on this, adding some more info in here based on the test that was ran, the following is some examples I've taken to see how long it took:

```
Tue Nov 28 16:49:29.074897
Tue Nov 28 16:49:29.357597
0.28 seconds to send

Tue Nov 28 16:49:29.366940
Tue Nov 28 16:49:29.500178
0.14 seconds to send

Tue Nov 28 16:49:29.510758
Tue Nov 28 16:49:29.635567
0.12 seconds to send

Tue Nov 28 16:49:29.645406
Tue Nov 28 16:49:29.776114
0.13 seconds to send

Tue Nov 28 16:58:28.549093
Tue Nov 28 16:58:28.907755
0.36 seconds to send

Tue Nov 28 16:58:28.917883
Tue Nov 28 16:58:29.041314
0.13 seconds to send

Tue Nov 28 16:58:29.051385
Tue Nov 28 16:58:29.322760
0.27 seconds to send
```

The first timestamp is taken from the first Server to Client message in the logs which is the Mail Relay welcome message and the last timestamp is the Bye message from the Server to Client.

If I look at the amount of content, it seems to take some time to send that line by line from CLIENT to Server, an example is
First Time Stamp of HTML content: 16:58:27.144792
Last Time Stamp of HTML content: 16:58:27.167857
Not sure if I should be expecting it to take this long to send the content to the server?

I can then also see that there is a 0.06 seconds gap between:
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS\r\n
and the next line:
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO
Unsure if this is normal?

After all the content is sent to the Mail Relay, there is a 0.06 second gap before the relay confirms OK Queued
Again, not sure if I should expect a more instant response?

Here is the main code that sends the email:

```
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$addresses = explode(',', $customerlist);
foreach ($addresses as $address) {
    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
    $mail->addBCC($address);
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        $emailoutput .= "Mail <font color=red><b>Not</font></b> Sent to $address - <b>Error:</b> $mail->ErrorInfo<br>";
    }
    else {
        $emailoutput .= "Mail <font color=green><b>Successfully</font></b> Sent to $address<br>";
    } 
}
```

Any help would be amazing
Thanks

Comment: 12 minutes to send 4500 emails seems reasonable. Many hosting companies throttle email to reduce load elsewhere on the network, and to avoid a reputation for spam. You'd do better to explain why this speed is a problem, and see what suggestions you can get for dealing with that.

Comment: Added some more notes to help guys, thanks!

Comment: Is this a scheduled job? You could run multiple instances of the PHP script in parallel, each dealing with a different batch of the data. P.S. `It took 12 minutes to send`...I assume you mean the PHP script takes 12 minutes to execute, specifically? Or are you counting the mailserver's processing time in that figure?

Comment: You can't make the script faster until you know what part of the script is slow. Is it the message generation? The network connection? Database hits? You'll need to do some profiling before you tackle this.

Comment: The timing of 12 minutes is from the first SMTPDEBUG log coming from phpmailer to the last entry so it’s local I would say?

Comment: Yeah that's basically the timing of the PHP script then (unless you do anything significant before you start sending mail?). Obviously it depends a bit on how fast the mailserver responds to each request, but probably it's fairly quick in each case I'd guess. As Alex says though, you really need to log carefully (or look carefully at existing logs) to see if there's a specific bottleneck anywhere

Comment: With this many emails going out regularly, you'll certainly want to track bounces and opt-outs, and you'll probably also want the ability to measure engagement -- all of which can be done very simply if you switch to a 3rd party service. Sending this much unmonitored automated volume through a local gateway is a good way to get blacklisted, and if other company mail is dependent on that same gateway, you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: Thanks guys, the emails being sent are HTML content (with some php variables) taken from an ob_start/end method. I’m thinking that I could try reduce the HTML involved which could help too?

Comment: Nah, that's just tickling around the edges. Unless your email content is huge (several MB) then that won't make the slightest difference I'd have thought. Parallel execution of some sort is far more likely to bring results in terms of performance - although, again, you should really try to do some serious investigation to really pinpoint a slow area before you embark on any major changes.

Comment: I’ll see what else I can spot based on the test run I did but it genuinely did seem quick, just overall it all adds up when it’s doing the same thing over 4.5k times. I will also confirm that each email is exactly the same content, I originally had everyone in a single email as BCC but I was asked to alter it so each recipient gets an email with them in the address field and hence this problem. This isn’t for anything marketing related it’s purely notices to a customer base and all sent from a registered domain and mailbox

Comment: Also, don't assume that there's no throttle just because it's a private server. Whatever mail service it's running probably has a reasonable default configured out of the box.

Comment: Fair point Alex, any ideas what areas I could get the team to check? Pretty sure it’s Postfix they’re using

Comment: The [config file](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) has quite a few settings named `*_rate_limit`

Comment: I have added a bunch more information to the main content based on me looking at logs some more today

Comment: Thanks. `Not sure if I should be expecting it to take this long to send the content to the server`... well it's a small fraction of a second so I doubt you can really worry about it.  `there is a 0.6 seconds gap`...that I'm not sure about. Maybe talk to your mailserver admins and see if they think that's typical for the server. But...are you opening a new connection to the server every time you send a single mail? Possibly your PHP code can be optimised, but we can't see it.

Comment: Added the main code, I don't believe I have starting a new connection to the server for every email, although the logs do give that effect?

Comment: Yeah that snippet doesn't at least looks like it doesn't need any particular optimisation

Comment: One of the reasons I'm the maintainer of PHPMailer is that I use it as a core part of [smartmessages.net](https://info.smartmessages.net). In that role I do indeed use parallel senders, and I'm happily sustaining the submission of about 275 messages/sec. If you've not done so already, I suggest looking at [the mailing list example code](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) and reading [the docs on sending to lists](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Sending-to-lists).

Comment: The STARTTLS setup time is insignificant if you use keepalive as it only happens once per batch, but you can eliminate even that by using SMTPS mode (`SMTPSecure = 'ssl'` and port 465), which is recommended anyway for security.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of those elements, I wasn't using Keepalive until I started looking at all this but I am now and it has shown improvements. Still not quite where I want to be